# Set visibility via bindings - dimens.xml

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, visibility

Is it possible to set the visibility via bindings? (dimens.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="@whatever/visibility_of_this_view"
android:orientation="horizontal">...
```

so that I can put something inside of the dimens.xml like:

```
<whatever name="visibility_of_this_view">visible</whatever>
```

I don't want to do it via code or different layouts, just with different dimens.xml.

Comment: use <string name="visibility_of_this_view">visible</string> instead

Comment: string does not work because visibility is an integer. it is possible to use integer values like the constants View.VISIBLE, but this is not a really good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How ever your different dimens are selected (layout, api, what ever) you should use the same mechanism to select another layout or even a different style which sets the visibility. Every other way seems to be a abusive way :)